# Error while calculating time diff

Tags: python

I am running into following error while calculating time diff?how to fix it?

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
print "Start : %s" % time.ctime()
start_time = time.ctime()
#do something
print "How to calculate time diff?"
end_time = time.ctime()
total_elapsed_time = datetime.combine(date.today(), end_time) - datetime.combine(date.today(), start_time)
print "TOTAL ELAPSED TIME" +  str(total_elapsed_time)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_diff.py", line 8, in <module>
    total_elapsed_time = datetime.combine(date.today(), end_time) - datetime.combine(date.today(), start_time)
TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not str
```

Comment: `time.ctime()` return you string `Fri Jul  1 05:16:25 2016`, you cannot calculate diff on that

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar - ok then,how do I calculate time diff and print in an understandable format?

Comment: You need to have a datetime instance. By using datetime instances you can then after calculating difference show it in a human readable format.

Comment: I've posted an more "elaborate" answer pointing why your code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are mixin 3 data types, so your approach is fundamentally wrong.

There are two (basic) ways, how to get and store time in python (two from std lib):

1. timestamp - you import `time` module, then `time.time()` will return a `float` - a number of seconds from epoch, then any comparison is just like comparing float numbers, if number is greater - then time that it represents is in the future, any difference between dates is a number too - representing number of seconds between dates - so it is as well simple to convert it minutes, hours etc. by dividing by 60, 3600 etc.
2. `datetime` object you import `datetime.datetime` to get an object which you can operate on, it is much simpler to operate on than timestamp, because it is automatically converted to human readable format, all comparison operators works and any difference between dates (date2-date1) is returned as `datetime.timedelta` where you can extract number of days, seconds and milliseconds it represents.

so in your code you can use:

timestamps:

```
import time

date1 = time.time()
print 'Start time: %s' % time.ctime(date1)
...
date2 = time.time()
print 'End time: %s' % time.ctime(date2)

print 'Time it took: %0.2f seconds' % (date2 - date1)
```

datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.now()
print 'Start time: %s' % date1
...
date2 = datetime.now()
print 'End time: %s' % date2

print 'Time it took: %s' % (date2 - date1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly states that argument 2 of combine() must be datetime.time.

You should have an instance of `datetime.time` which is something like:

```
d = datetime.now()
timepart = d.time()
datepart = d.date()
datetime.combine(datepart, timepart)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def calc():
    s = datetime.now()
    e = datetime(day=21, month=7, year=2016, hour=12, minute=0)

    diff = e - s
```

**diff** is datetime.timedelta instance now. On this instance you have properties such as days, seconds, microseconds and function by name total_seconds.

**PS:** This is for reference only. I hope it helps to achieve a solution

Answer (score 0):

time.ctime() returns a string, that is the source of your error.

[See Python time.ctime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_ctime.htm)

time.time() is probably what you are looking for:

[See Python ticks](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_date_time.htm)

Comment: I already tried that,using time.time() throws `TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not float`

Answer (score 0):

Your start_time and end_time are strings. Also your datetime.combine should have the 2nd argument as a datetime.time object. Your time.ctime returns the date and year information as well. So first extract only the time information and then convert it to a datetime.time object.

You can store the start and end time both using ctime and then do something like this:

```
import datetime
import time
#store at start time
a=datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
#store at end time
b=datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print b-a
```

As @Jerzyk pointed out, there is no need to parse it unless you want to display it in a particular format. So alternatively, you could do:

```
a=datetime.datetime.now()
b=datetime.datetime.now()
print b-a
```

This will return a datetime.timedelta that you can parse in order to display the result in the way you want.

Comment: this solution make no sense whatsoever, why convert timestamp to string then t parse it? paring is very expensive. store time as datetime or timestamp, and then convert it only when needed to display this should not be mareked as a solution because it will sugest somebody new to use such a approach

Comment: You are right about that. Alternatively, or rather more efficiently, you can use datetime.datetime.now() for both the start and end dates and compute the difference. This will return a timedelta object which can in turn be formatted into a string if and when required. I shall edit my answer to include this. Thanks !

Comment: sorry for my strong comment, but your solution will not work for different locales - ctime output depends on the active locale, therefore parsing pattern will not match, the only way to do this correctly is to use timestamps or datetime objects.

Comment: Not a problem. Your comment showed me where I have erred! I'm a python noob myself so it's a great learning opportunity. About the first solution, I wasn't very clear about the scope of the problem so I worked with what I had. Didn't really take the locales under consideration!